# Camel 2.12.3 gives exception related to XmlConverter

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting the following exception at runtime after switching from `Camel 2.12.2` to `Camel 2.12.3`
I get same exception even with `Camel 2.13.0` and `Camel 2.13.1` also.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class does not support JDK1.5
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.setFeature(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:317)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxp.XmlConverter.createTransformerFactory(XmlConverter.java:994)
```

I am usnig `Java6`,`Tomcat6.0.36`. Also i do have `xalan 2.7.1`.

I googled it and came across following workaround also:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-XmlConverter-after-upgrade-to-2-12-3-td5748082.html#none

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28%29)

```
. Add system properties : (any one of below implementation class works fine)
-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

. Or you can add a “`jaxp.properties`” in your `jre\lib` folder 
                With contents of `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl   (Again here also you can give any of above 3 implementation class)`

Problem is i am not getting whats happening internally that makes it work with `camel 2.12.2` and fails with newer versions. And why it is showing a wrong message complaing about `jdk1.5` ?

I think problem is somehwhere it is not able to find correct implementation of `TransformerFactory` 
at this point (not sure)

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

Thanks in advance.